# Passing multiple checkbox values in AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use a ternary operator to check which checkboxes in a form have been selected. If a value has been selected, I affix the name-value pair to a query string which is then passed in an AJAX call. If not, I attach a name with an empty string value.

It works fine, I'm just wondering if there's a more compact/elegant way to do this as it seems somewhat verbose. I'm wondering if it's possible to use a for loop. The reason I'm not sure if this would work is it would involve dynamically assigning variable names within the loop based on the index.

```
    var fields = $('input[name="apn"]').serializeArray();
    var apn1 = fields[0] ? fields[0]["value"] : '' 
    query += '&apn1=' + apn1;
    var apn2 = fields[1] ? fields[1]["value"] : '' 
    query += '&apn2=' + apn2;
    var apn3 = fields[2] ? fields[2]["value"] : '' 
    query += '&apn3=' + apn3;
    var apn4 = fields[3] ? fields[3]["value"] : '' 
    query += '&apn4=' + apn4;
    var apn5 = fields[4] ? fields[4]["value"] : '' 
    query += '&apn5=' + apn5;
    ...
```

Comment: Thinking about it some more, it seems like it might make sense to simply pass an array instead...

Comment: Have you tried [`var query = $.param(fields);`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)?

Answer (score 0):

Map the values and indices to an array of objects, and just pass that directly to $.ajax, jQuery will use $.param on it for you :

```
var fields = $.map($('input[name="apn"]'), function(el, i) {
    var o = {};
    o['apn' + i] = el.value;
    return o;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If its just checkboxes:

```
$('input[name="apn"]').each(function (i, el) {
    if($(el).is(':checked')) {
        query += '&apn'+i+'=' + el.value;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply serialize the form:

```
var query = $("#FormId").serialize();
```